# Spark SQL - ERROR XJ040

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the new features of pyspark.sql. The code I'm running is as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/tmp").appName("PopularMovies").getOrCreate()
lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("...some file...")
movies = lines.map(...some function...)
movieDataset = spark.createDataFrame(movies)
```

It was working perfectly but all of a sudden when running this operation a second time in interactive mode I've started receiving an ERROR XJ040:

```
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@6b669cdf, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 97 more
```

Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\Users\giovanni.bruner\metastore_db.

Anyone got any idea how this could be resolved? Restarting the command prompt or even the machine didn't change the situation.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of spark running (eg using notebooks and you have more than one running at the same time?)

Comment: Not that I'm able to tell David, I'm running Spark in interactive mode, shutting down and restarting the command prompt. Can it be that it keeps running under the hood?